# React Router - Login redirect to a private route goes to landing page instead

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I have authentication up and running, but I am trying to get a redirect to the (private route) application page after a successful sign in. Instead a user is redirected to the landing page, in which they have to navigate to the application page manually.

My route is wrapped as follows

```
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/app" component={AppHome} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Where the login component checks and redirects via

```
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser)
    return <Redirect to="/app" />
  }
```

Full login component

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import FBase from '../firebase.js'
import { AuthContext } from '../auth/Auth'

const Login = ({ history }) => {
  const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await FBase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        history.push('/')
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    },
    [history]
  );

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser)
    return <Redirect to="/app" />
  }

  return (
    ///UI - Form calls handleLogin
  )
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

Console is clearly logging the user after a successful sign in, so this may be a lifecycle issue.

The private route itself (the redirect in here works)

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render = {routeProps => !!currentUser ? (
        <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
      ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

After further testing, it seems the redirect just doesn't work at all, as I've tried redirecting to signup too.

Comment: Can you show the full "Login" Component?

Comment: In your `PrivateRoute` Component, can you console.log(currentUser) successfully after login?

Comment: Added login component to original post.

Comment: Also, yes. Both the PrivateRoute and Login components' console logs successfully log the currentUser after a login.

Comment: You have in your handleLogin function:  `history.push('/')`
This will redirect the user to the home page.

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the wrong place entirely. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use useHistory hook to handle redirection, it's easier and you can directly implement it in your async/await function.

```js
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
const history = useHistory()

async function foo(){
 const res = await stuff
 history.push("/app")
}
```

Also, don't write exact path everywhere in your route. This is only necessary for the main root "/".